# Is it possible to set key for assoc results from db?

Tags: php, laravel

When getting result from db is it possible to setup field name that would be the key in the array? lists method not suitable as there is more than 1 value.

Basicaly i have:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DevID"]=>
    string(6) "448805"
    ["Active"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["SiteType"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DevID"]=>
    string(6) "487195"
    ["Active"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["SiteType"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DevID"]=>
    string(6) "487732"
    ["Active"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["SiteType"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DevID"]=>
    string(6) "488805"
    ["Active"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["SiteType"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

And i need:

```
array(4) {
  [448805]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DevID"]=>
    string(6) "448805"
    ["Active"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["SiteType"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [487195]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DevID"]=>
    string(6) "487195"
    ["Active"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["SiteType"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [487732]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DevID"]=>
    string(6) "487732"
    ["Active"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["SiteType"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [488805]=>
  array(3) {
    ["DevID"]=>
    string(6) "488805"
    ["Active"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["SiteType"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Just do a loop through the first array and create the second with the data in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the first array and create another array with the data in the first.

```
$arr2 = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $val) {
   $arr2[$val['DevID']] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find myself doing this a lot, so I created a function for it:

```
function array_index(array $array, $key)
{
    $index = array();
    $count = count($array);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $array[$i]))
        {
            continue;
        }

        $index[$array[$i][$key]] = $array[$i];
    }

    return $index;
}
```

Usage:

```
$index = array_index($yourDbResult, 'DevID');
```

Here's a similar function, but you pass a callable as the key. The callable will receive each item in the array, and its return value will be used as the indexing key. Useful for performing some manipulation on the index key.

```
function array_index_callback(array $array, $callback)
{
    $index = array();
    $count = count($array);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        $indexKey = $callback($array[$i]);
        $index[$indexKey] = $array[$i];
    }

    return $index;
}
```

Usage:

```
$index = array_index_callback($yourDbResult, function(&$item) {
    return 'id_'.$item['DevID'];
});
```